# Crash in textViewShouldBeginEditing

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

My app is live and I see crash in `textViewShouldBeginEditing`. Symbolicating crash log in Organiser and opening project in xCode takes me to following line - see // Thread 0.

I'm unable to figure out what is wrong here. how do I find issue and fix it?

[Crash Trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TGdR.png)

```
func textViewShouldBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) -> Bool {
    guard let balance = self.balance, let cost = self.profile.cost else {
        return false
    } // Thread 0

    if balance.isLess(than: Float(cost)!) {
        self.showLowBalanceAlert()
        self.sendButton.isEnabled = false
        self.sendButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        return false
    }

    if let blockedStatus = self.blockedStatus {
        if blockedStatus.blocked! {
            self.showAleart(message: "Blocked")
            self.sendButton.isEnabled = false
            self.sendButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: Show the complete method. Show the complete error message and relevant portion of the stack trace.

Comment: I've updated with full code and crash trace screenshot.

Comment: `Float(cost)!` Is it really a valid value? Why not doing also a `if let costFloat = Float(cost)`? Same for `if blockedStatus.blocked!`, `if blockedStatus.blocked ?? false` (or true, depend on what you want)?

Comment: So this xCode->Organizer->Crashes->Open crash log in project doesn't' point to exact line where crash has occurred? In my case it takes me to the line where I've added // Thread 0.